# How to share cache between two different keys

Tags: reactjs, swr

Im using SWR, I have a register endpoint `/register` that uses `useSWRMutation` which does some auth logic and returns user data with a post request, and another endpoint `/user/me`  which returns user data with `useSWR` with a get request.

How can I populate the cache so that when I call `useSWR` with key `/user/me` it returns the data from `useSWRMutation` with key `/register`instead of actually making an api call?